# result of mysql AES_DECRYPT

Tags: php, mysql

i save a password with AES_ENCRYPT in my mysql DB, now i have a little function to get the decrypted password back.

This is the function

```
function get_clear_pw($tab,$param)
{
    global $m;
    if($_SESSION['APP4']['SITEID']<=0 or $_SESSION['ACTIVE_USER']['ID']<=0){ return 'no way'; }

    $query[1]="WHERE `SITEID`='".$_SESSION['APP4']['SITEID']."' ";
    $query[0]="SELECT AES_DECRYPT(PW,'mykey')  FROM";
    $resDB=app_db($m['ID'].'_SITE_'.$tab, $query, '');
    $resDB=$resDB[0];
    return $resDB;
}
```

As result for

```
$pw=get_clear_pw('FTP',FALSE);
Print_r($pw)
```

i get this
Array ( [AES_DECRYPT(PW,'meinkey')] => test )

Now i want to have echo $pw => 'test' or echo $pw[0] => 'test'

I dont want to have "AES_DECRYPT(PW,'mykey')" as the key.

How can i do that?

Comment: yes i know, in this special case i need to encrypt

Comment: you should add a `as`: `AES_DECRYPT(PW,'mykey') AS password`

Comment: There is *no* special case that I know of which should allow passwords to be decrypted.

Comment: @Magnus - yes, thats it is - thank you

Answer (score 0):

Usually for passwords one way hash used.
It is a security measure to make sure that if somebody gets on your server they can not decrypt passwords.

In this situation when user enters password on a login you just hash it same way and compare hashed values.

Look in to

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

For php version 5.5+

Comment: so it is, but in this case this are external passwords, so i cant check them by myself, thats the reason why i have to decrypt them

Comment: Someone is allowing you access to external passwords? Good grief!